# Can't access Imported Node Module from within Node stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why can't I access this?

**someFile.js**

```
const Context = require('./Context');

    const play = function(){
      process.openStdin().on('data', function(res) {
         if(Context.move(res, X)){ // I get an error here saying Context is undefined
            ... rest of the code
          }
   }
```

I'd like to not have to modify the behavior, the code in play as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in any kind of modern Node, preserve your context with an arrow function:

```
const Context = require('./Context');

const play = () => {
  process.openStdin().on('data', res => {
     if(Context.move(res, X)){
        ... rest of the code
     }
  });
};
```

Comment: ok cool.  I'm trying not to edit this legacy code, I'm adding coverage around it so I can get confidence before doing refactorings but if this is the only way fine...

Comment: See, that part needs to be in your question. Read over ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) for a moment, and then update your question to include all those juicy and *super important* details like which versions of Node you're tied to, maybe an [mcve] that shows up the actual use case, etc. =)

Comment: That said, the only supported versions of Node today are v6 and up, which should all support arrow functions. If you're on Node 4 or below: you are literally a security vulnerability at this point in time, so start uplifting your codebase.

Comment: An arrow function does not make a difference here. There is no difference between arrow and non-arrow wrt how variables are resolved. The only difference is how `this` is handled (which the OP is not using).